# PHP prematurely exiting while loop

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, guzzle

Pretty new to PHP and I am stuck on a (what I consider) a strange issue. I have spliced this file together, (it was split across several different functions) for testing, and to make it easier to explain the issue.

This is a basic while loop in Laravel and it seems to be exiting prematurely but oddly not exiting out to the line AFTER the loop, but exiting out BEFORE the loop and then entering again. Can't for the life of me workout why. I have added some log events throughout the function so I could try understand what was happening.

This is correctly fetching and writting products to the DB up until page 7 and then I get a "Start API Helper" event on log but never get an "End API helper". So somewhere in page 7 something is causing the while loop to exit out to the lines above, reset the pagecount to 0. then re-enter the loop, fetching the first lot of products and throwing an SQL duplicate key exception when writing. I know it is exiting out to before the loop as I get a "Before while", right after "New Client" in the log. And of course, the pagecount is resetting. How can this happen?

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

```
public function store()
{
    $items = array();
    Log::info('Before while');
    $pagecount = 0;
    $prodcount = 1;
     while ($prodcount > 0) {
        Log::info('Top of while');
        $prodcount = 0; // Reset product counter
        Log::info('Page Count:'.$pagecount);
        Log::info('Start API Helper');
    $headers = array(
        'NETOAPI_KEY' => env('NETO_API_KEY'),
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'NETOAPI_ACTION' => 'GetItem'
    );
    Log::info('Headers Declared');
    $body = '{
        "Filter": {
            "DateAddedFrom" : "2013-06-01 12:00:00",
            "Page": "'.$pagecount.'",
            "Limit": "500",
            "OutputSelector": [
                **Lots of JSON here - removed for readability**
            ]
        }
    }'; 

    Log::info('Start API Helper');
    $client = new client();
    Log::info('New Client');
    try {
       $res = $client->post(env('NETO_API_URL'), [ 'headers' => $headers , 'body' => $body ]);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getRequest();
        Log::error($e->getRequest());
        if ($e->hasResponse()) {
            echo $e->getResponse();
            Log::error($e->getResponse());
        }
    }
    Log::info('End API Helper');
    $items = json_decode(utf8_encode($res->getBody()), true);
        foreach($items["Item"] as $item)
        {
            // JSON is returning an empty array for empty strings. Need to convert to empty string for SQL save.
            foreach($item as $key => $value){
                if (empty($value)) {
                     $item["$key"] = "";
                }
            }
            $Product = new Item;
            $Product->SKU = array_get($item, 'SKU');
            ** LOTS OF DB FIELDS REMOVED FROM HERE FOR READABILITY**
            $Product->save();
            $prodcount++;               
        } 
        $pagecount++;
        Log::info($prodcount.' products written to DB:');
        Log::info('Bottom of while'); 
    };
    Log::info('Exited While'); 
    return 'Complete';
}
```

**UPDATE:** I have modified the ELoquent SQL Client to a firstorNew to avoid any potential Duplicate key errors. Now the logs show the same 'while exit' at page 7 (occasionally page 8) which then re-enters the loop at page 0 BUT the weirdest thing is that it seems to end up with 2 instances of the loop running. Then eventually 3 instances, then 4. Then it throws a memory exhausted exception. The logs looks like.

```
local.INFO: Page Count:1
local.INFO: Page Count:2
local.INFO: Page Count:3
local.INFO: Page Count:4 
local.INFO: Page Count:5 
local.INFO: Page Count:6 
local.INFO: Page Count:7 
local.INFO: Page Count:8
local.INFO: Page Count:0
local.INFO: Page Count:9
local.INFO: Page Count:1
local.INFO: Page Count:10 
local.INFO: Page Count:2
local.INFO: Page Count:11 
local.INFO: Page Count:3
local.INFO: Page Count:12
```

...And so on...

Is it possible that a malformed JSON API response could be causing this? Perhaps I'll try limit the paging to 25 or so, so I can access the response causing the loop break?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess as of page 7 you run out of rows to process and the following API call fails in some way:

```
try {
       $res = $client->post(env('NETO_API_URL'), [ 'headers' => $headers , 'body' => $body ]);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getRequest();
        Log::error($e->getRequest());
        if ($e->hasResponse()) {
            echo $e->getResponse();
            Log::error($e->getResponse());
        }
    }
```

As to how your loop re-enters is likely because you wrapped the store method in another try catch which re-attempts? As I can't see any try catch inside the function which would indicate loop re-start.

My advice would be to re-write your method as a do-while loop and modify your while condition to be:

```
while ($prodcount === 500)
```

This would ensure you don't make any sub-sequent API calls that you know to have no meaning and also reduce the likelihood of issues in your code.

Another nice check to make would be on your response object:

```
if (!isset($items["Item"])) {
    echo 'Response contains no "Item" value';
    exit;
}
```

Other than that, this is hard to de-bug without putting more logging and more var_dump() / print_r() to step through your logic.

Goodluck.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thank-you so much for the response. I have modified the loop to a do-while which was a a great idea thanks! I have also added the empty array loop exit. I am still stuck on the loop issue of course. There are many more pages of products following page 7. I have modified the Eloquent to a firstOrNew which will update or create a DB record. This has resolved the duplicate key issue and will leave the process running then sus the logs to see if that sheds anymore light on the issue. Thanks again.